# How to TypeScript a react 'map-like' get function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to TS and struggling to type the following arrow function:

```
const mapLikeGet = (obj, key) => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
        return obj[key]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics and set the first variable must be an object and the second variable the k of the object and the result will be the `O[key]` or `undefined`.

```
const mapLikeGet = <O extends Object, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, key: K): O[K] | undefined => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
        return obj[key];
    }
    return undefined;
}

// foo
const foo = {
    one: 1,
    two: "",
};


const oneVal = mapLikeGet(foo, "one");
// oneVal => number | undefined
```

In `Typescript 4.9` you could use the `in` operator. (See: [Announcing TypeScript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#in-narrowing)):

```
const mapLikeGet = <O extends Object, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, key: ): O[K] | undefined => {
    if (key in obj) {
        return obj[key];
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type it using generics and `keyof`:

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4BkCWBrApgcS7AXhgB4AVAGgD4AKEAIwCsAuGCmbATxc5ADNWAlDAKUYAbwCwAKBiyYaftQDyjLMCgA6JACcQUPRyRYNACwQQlAdzAAFXUe1QOG4AgA2b2o3LssHAQLScsEw2vgArtpgMPQMANqcALpBcmFQkdHhYAAmWLxoYFjZANzSAL5AA)

```
const mapLikeGet = <T,>(obj: T, key: keyof T) => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
        return obj[key]
    return undefined;
}

const foo = mapLikeGet({ foo: "bar"}, "foo");
    // ^? const foo: string | undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answers, and considering that the person asking is a beginner, I think this should be as simple as possible:

```js
const mapLikeGet = (obj : any, key : string) => {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
        return obj[key]
}
```

The fact you are using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` means that you are not even assuming that `obj` inherits from `Object`, hence I see this as a perfect case for using the `any` type.

The `key`, on the other hand, is obviously a string.

Comment: `any` should never be used. `unknown` would be preferable in this case.

Comment: In this you will get always `any` as return. In that case, you need to revalidate the type of the response out of the function and if you want to mix it with `is [a type]` you could have some future problems. I don't recommend use `any` in production code only if it is really necessary and know what are you doing.